# Performances issue when you bind several actions to a event Listener

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6, listener, addeventlistener

lets use the `scroll` listener example.

If we have too many elements (20 for example ) which those needs to do something on a certain scroll params.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // condition 1 -> if true doSomething()
  // condition 2 -> if true doSomething2()
  // condition 3 -> if true doSomething3()
  //...etc
});
```

We gonna have a listener with more than 20 conditionals. This is good ?
or would be better to have different scroll event listener.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // condition 1 -> if true doSomething()
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // condition 2 -> if true doSomething2()
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // condition 3 -> if true doSomething3()
});  // ...etc
```

I'm not sure how this is gonna be compiled behind the scenes and which one is a better approach.

Comment: The first one would be probably better.

Comment: I don't think adding multiple event listeners will help, try `console.dir(e);` inside you event listener and see how can you use the detailed event properties to handle your multiple conditions.

Comment: The first one. Especially when you can be clever about the conditions and share computations.

Answer (score 2):

The first would be preferable because it's just a single function. In the second format, all 20 scroll handlers would need to be invoked, even if the `if` statement in only one of them actually matches. Also, the scroll event is known to be intensive as it can fire *a lot*.

But that single function can be improved without too much effort. Instead of having a massive `if` statement with twenty branches (for twenty elements), you could use an object mapping instead, something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    const handlers = {
      elementId1: function() {
          // handle element 1
      },
      element2Id: function() {
          // handle element 2
      },
      etc...
    };

    handlers[e.target.id]();
});
```

In this case you just need to ensure that the relevant DOM elements have the correct `id` attributes. This avoids the conditional logic. The point is not that this specific code is 'the best', just that there are ways to avoid large `if` statements.

Comment: This looks really interesting, i was thinking about multiple listener just because i thought that i could Debounce some of them. Because maybe you know, we can have some conditions those don't need to be checked all the time.

Answer (score 1):

As danwellman response suggests the `scroll` event will be fired several times/msec. This can cause an overhead in terms of resources, memory allocation, etc. so I suggest you to use a throttle function:

```
     /* 
      * Returns a function, that, when invoked, will only be triggered at most once
     * during a given window of time. Normally, the throttled function will run
     * as much as it can, without ever going more than once per `wait` duration;
     * but if you'd like to disable the execution on the leading edge, pass
     * `{leading: false}`. To disable execution on the trailing edge, ditto.
    */
   var throttle = function(func, wait, options) {
        var context, args, result;
        var timeout = null;
        var previous = 0;
        if (!options) options = {};
        var later = function() {
            previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
            timeout = null;
            result = func.apply(context, args);
            if (!timeout) context = args = null;
        };
        return function() {
            var now = Date.now();
            if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
            var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
            context = this;
            args = arguments;
            if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
            if (timeout) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = null;
            }
            previous = now;
            result = func.apply(context, args);
            if (!timeout) context = args = null;
            } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
            timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
            }
            return result;
        };
    }
```

Now you add the normal scroll event:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log("scroll event")
});
```

and the throttled one just for comparison:

```
window.onscroll= throttle( function(e) { console.log("throttled scroll event") }, 1000 * 5, {leading:false})
```

This will be fired not less than every 5 seconds, so in the console you will se the difference among them:

```
(126) scroll event
throttled scroll event
(15) scroll event
throttled scroll event
```

Comment: Yeah that is a must, i'm already using the lodash library for the debounce and throttle methods.

But i was more worried about if 2 event listener would increase the memory consuming by 2, instead of put all the logic inside one if it's possible